# Match a character multiple times with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find list of substrings present in another string.

Here is what i'm thinking:

```
preg_match_all("/foot|ball|football/", "I like football", $results);
```

Result:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "foot",
        1 => "ball"
    )
)
```

https://regexr.com/3j0db

As you can see, it matches `foot` and `ball` but not `football`

I've tried different flags, php options and ordering of the regex retring with no luck.

I'm unable to get them all to match.

What i figured out that on single character can only be matched once.
It is able to search "bacwards", eg if i change the regex to `/ball|foot|football/` moving the ball before foot, both will get matched but football will not.

Also i've tried this with PCRE (php) and Javascript - same results.

**Can i get them all to match?**

Comment: Do you want to get `foot`, `ball` and `football`? Like [this](https://ideone.com/VhuVNT) with `'~(foot)(ball)?~'` pattern?

Comment: If you want select full word - `/\b(foot|ball|football)\b/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve but the input is dynamic so I cannot write there rules by hand...

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the real life problem.

Comment: After a match is found, further searching will only continue _after_ that match. If you want to find all those words, then you should check for each one of them individually, in a loop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is a real world problem with simplified example. IMO,
 [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) applies to stackexchange also

Comment: @Kristian Rather than "accept" an answer that you know to be inefficient, you should post your `strpos()` solution as an answer and accept your own answer.  Keep in mind, countless future readers will see this page -- some of them won't know the difference between "poor practice" and "best practice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all results, you can use this code:

```
$allMatches = [];
$words = ['foot', 'ball', 'football'];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (preg_match("/$word/", 'I like football', $result)) {
        $allMatches = array_merge($allMatches, $result);
    }
}

print_r($allMatches);
```

This problem due to the existance of foot and ball in football, so you should test every word separately.

Comment: That's what I thought that this is limited by the regex engine. I end up using the same loop but will use `strpos('I like football', $word) !== FALSE` when regex is not needed for a word as it performs better.